# How to quantify the difference between $2$ ellipses?

Tags: conic-sections, regression

In my research I try to identify parameters defining an equation of ellipsoid. I have 3 unknowns and my ellipse is always centered at the origin but the rotation varies (see attached figure).

[image: Plot of reference and identified ellipses]

I would like to have some method for quantifying how good my identification was knowing the reference parameters.

Initially I thought of Coefficient of Determination, but I'm not sure if it's applicable to that problem. The values I obtain are very close to 1 (the ellipse shown in the figure has R2 = 0.990) so I'm not very confident if this tool is reliable to distinguish between different sets of parameters.

Another idea was to compare areas of each ellipse, but here the problem lies in rotation - the area is conserved through rotation, but clearly two rotated ellipses are not the same.
The area between the ellipses is another idea, but here I struggle with integration limits.

Any suggestions how reliably could I quantify accuracy of my parameters?

EDIT:
My model is based on 3 parameters:
$\sigma_{11}^{y}, \sigma_{22}^{y}, \sigma_{33}^{y}$
And the curve (in $\sigma_{11} - \sigma_{22}$ space) I construct is as follows:

$\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{11}^{y}}\right)^{2} \sigma^{2}_{11} -\left[\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{11}^{y}}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{22}^{y}}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{33}^{y}}\right)^{2}\right] \sigma_{11} \sigma_{22} + \left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{22}^{y}}\right)^{2} \sigma^{2}_{22} - \left(\sigma_{11}^{y}\right)^{2} = 0$

Comment: I hope you can explain your question in more detail. What is the initial data you are working with? How and where are you going to use the approximate parameters of the ellipse once you obtain them?

Comment: you could try to integrate the difference between the 2 curves

Comment: @You'reInMyEye why is initial data or later usage relevant? He has 2 ellipses, one "standard" and one "approximate" and is trying to quantify how one approximates the other...

Comment: The answer to your question will depend in part on how you wish to measure 'how good' your approximation is. There are, at the outset a plethora of ways to go about it.

Comment: @gt6989b, what if for example the OP wants to get a better approximation from the initial one? How is the integral difference going to help them? That's why I'm asking for clarification

Comment: @JustinBenfield if you could list possibilities it would be very useful to me. I will test all anyway and see which one suits me the best.

Comment: @gt6989b any tips how to integrate the difference if the domain is not compatible ? (One ellipse will always by further to right/left where the other is not well defined)

Comment: @You'reInMyEye I've added a little to the original post. The parameters I identified are a final point of a long algorithm involving calibration of a plasticity model for metals. The model is elliptic - hence my question. Due to different methods I use, the experimental noise is processed differently and so I identify parameters with different accuracy. I would like to have a value that compares outcomes obtained with different methods. Comparing parameter by parameter is not useful as there might be some compensations within a model so I wanted to have a measure how 'identify' model deviates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, one way to measure the difference is to integrate (in polar coordinates, e.g., with the origin coinciding with the center of both ellipses) the absolute value of the difference of how far each point lies away from the center.

In other words, if we consider $f(\theta)$ to be the distance of one ellipse from the origin in the angle of $\theta$, and $g(\theta)$ - of the other, we need
$$
D_{f,g} = \int_0^{2\pi} \left\|f(\theta) - g(\theta)\right\| \mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
where the norm could be $2$-norm or $1$-norm or any other convenient norm.

Comment: This makes sense (polar coordinates). +1

Comment: Thanks I really like this solution, it's really neat. My model if in fact full 3D ellipsoid (I skipped this part here) and this allows me to generalize easily error to 3D by performing integration in spherical coordinates, thanks!

Comment: @AlexMarek you are welcome, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If rotation was the only parameter that varied, then the only thing that would changes in your given equation is the coefficient of the $\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}$-term, hence you can compare how close they are by comparing that coefficient. However, you also have that the coefficient of $\sigma_{22}^2$ can change, as well as the constant term (which is $-(\sigma_{11}^y)^2$). Note that the coefficient of the $\sigma_{11}^2$-term is always $1$.

If we call $x=\sigma_{11}$, and $y=\sigma_{22}$, then your equation has the general form:

$x^2+Bxy+Cy^2+F=0$

Where

$B=-\left[\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{11}^{y}}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{22}^{y}}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{33}^{y}}\right)^{2}\right]$

$C=\left(\frac{\sigma_{11}^{y}}{\sigma_{22}^{y}}\right)^{2}$

and

$F=- \left(\sigma_{11}^{y}\right)^{2}$

$B$ controls rotation, $C$ the length ratio between major and minor axis ($C>0$ because of the square appearing on the RHS above, and nonzero because $\sigma_{11}$ must be nonzero else the result isn't an ellipse), finally $F$ controls the size of the ellipse (to see why, consider $x=0$, then the above equation becomes $Cy^2-F=0$)

The only question now is: How exactly do you want to 'put a number' to the error. Or in other words, how do you want to measure the error